# Doctrine ORM integration in framework

Tags: php, frameworks, doctrine

I'm trying to integrate the **Doctrine ORM** in my Framework. This is the basic structure of my framework.

```
├───app
│   ├───cache
│   ├───config
│   ├───controllers
│   ├───database
│   │   ├───mapping
│   │   ├───entities
│   │   └───repositories
│   ├───models
│   └───views
├───bin
├───framework
│   ├───cache
│   └───library
├───vendor
```

So i need to set the default path in Doctrine so that mapping, entity and repository files were generated on those directories:

```
├───database
│   ├───mapping
│   ├───entities
│   └───repositories
```

I've been reading the official documentation of **Doctrine ORM**, but I have not accomplished anything. I would appreciate if someone can help me a little. Sorry if i have orthographic failures.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.May it help u.

Let your framework be XYZ:
Make following changes in your index file.

```
require_once 'XYZ/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = XYZ_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()
 ->registerNamespace('Doctrine') 
 ->pushAutoloader(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
```